# C++ avoid dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

Imagine I have some `Node` struct that contains pointers to the left and right children and some data:

```cpp
struct Node {
  int data;
  Node *left;
  Node *right;
};
```

Now I want to do some state space search, and naturally I want to construct the graph as I go. So I will have a kind of loop that will have to create Nodes and keep them around. Something like:

```cpp
Node *curNode = ... ; // starting node

while (!done) {
  // ...
  curNode->left = new Node();
  curNode->right = new Node();
  // ..
  // Go left (for example)
  curNode = curNode->left;
}
```

The problem is that I have to dynamically allocate node on each iteration, which is slow. So the question is: how can I have pointers to some memory but *not by allocating it one by one*?

The first solution I thought of is to have a `std::vector<Node>` that will contain all the allocated nodes. The problem is that when we `push_back` elements, all references might be invalidated, so all my left/right pointers will be garbage.

The second solution is to allocate a big chunk of memory upfront, and then we just grab the next available pointer when we want to create a `Node`. To avoid references invalidation, we just have to create a linked list of big chunks of memory when we exceed the capacity of the current chunk so every given pointer stays valid. I think that `std::deque` behaves like this, but it's not explicitly created for this.

Another solution would be to store vector indices instead of pointers but this is not a solution because a `Node` doesn't want to be associated with any container, it wants the pointer directly.

So what is the good solution here, that would avoid having to allocated new nodes on each iteration?

Comment: `std::list<Node>`, `std::set<Node>`, `std::unordered_set<Node>`, `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>>` ... No relocation of the actual `Node`s.

Comment: You can use a `std::vector` of `nodes` if you call `reserve` upfront.  Reallocation will not then occur.

Comment: If you don't know how many nodes you need up-front or you want to periodically add nodes (but expect never to delete them), using `std::deque` might be appropriate.  This is like a budget version of an arena memory pool.  References to data inside the container are not invalidated by `push_front` or `push_back`.

Comment: I thiunk that's exactly what std::deque is for - you can add memory chunks at a time and not invalidate iterators.  But the other thing you might want to look at is one of the many pool allocators that are out there - a couple examples: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_1/libs/pool/doc/interfaces/pool_alloc.html  https://github.com/moya-lang/Allocator

Comment: Why does `Node` needs the pointer directly? Are you worrying about performance of double indirection? You could call the pair (container,index) an iterator, for `Node` it wpild be an opaque type behaving like `Node*` with dereferencing and `->`.

Comment: Who told you that `new` "is slow"? You'll be surprising to learn how fast memory allocation is. Certainly it's slower than construction in automatic scope, but it's mostly a nothing-burger on modern multi-Ghz CPUs. The major problems with `new` and `delete` isn't the performance.

Comment: I think that you should also avoid the owning raw pointers in your example. Consider using ```std::unique_ptr``` instead for no manual memory management.

Comment: All the solutions you suggest. You don't think the C++ memory management is already using those techniques under the hood!!! What makes you think that the code you write will be any faster (and it will definitely be buggier).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::deque<Node>` and it will do memory management for you creating elements by groups and no invalidating pointers if you do not delete elements in middle. Though if you want to have more precise control on how many elements in a group you can quite simply create something like that:

```
class NodePool {
    constexpr size_t blockSize = 512;
    using Block = std::array<Node,blockSize>;
    using Pool  = std::list<Block>;

    size_t allocated = blockSize;
    Pool   pool;
public:
    Node *allocate() 
    {
       if( allocated == blockSize ) {
           pool.emplace_back();
           allocated = 0;
       }
       return &( pool.back()[ allocated++ ] );
    }
};
```

I did not try to compile it, but it should be enough to exress the idea. Here changing `blockSize` you can fine tune performance of your program. Though you should be aware than `Node` objects will be fully constructed by groups (unlike hoiw `std::deque` would do it). As much as I am aware there is no way to create raw memory for Node objects which is standard comformant.